# Automation using gitlab jira integration

Tags: automation, scripting, gitlab, jira, integration

Does anyone know that, how could I automatically raise Jira issue by Gitlab jira integration? Is it possible to automaticaly raise Jira issue?

Answer (score 1):

The available features for the Jira-Gitlab integration are outlined here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html

Currently, there is no functionality for creating Jira issues, but you can link them to Gitlab Issues, close a Jira issue from a commit or merge request, and view Gitlab pipeline statuses in a linked Jira instance.

If you're a paid Gitlab user, you can also view all Jira issues within Gitlab.

Comment: Completely agree with you @Adam Marshall, I've been playing around with the Jira Issue tracker as well as with the DVCS Connector. However the integrations are not so helpful yet (as in June 2021) and there are are a lot of security concerns as well. There is a separate feature request (ID: 231406) is ongoing.